# Installing R packages to custom directory

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install a package to my own directory that I have read and write access to (I'm working on a server).

I use this command to successfully install the package: `install.packages('batch', lib='./packages', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/'` .

When I try to load the package with `library('batch')` I get this error:

```
Error in library("batch") : there is no package called 'batch'
```

When the package is finished installing I do get this notification: `The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/RtmpqTJrz5/downloaded_packages'`

All I want to do is simply load in the package. Maybe changing the `.libPaths()` but I'm not quite sure. I'm aware that you can use `load_all` in `devtools` but then I'd have to somehow load in that package, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you didn't specify to use your own library directory it is still looking in the default library. You need `lib.loc=`

```
library('batch', lib.loc="full.path.to.your_./packages_directory")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the little tip I needed.

Comment: This does not work anymore.   Error in installed.packages(lib.loc = libpath, fields = c("Package", "Version"), : formal argument "lib.loc" matched by multiple actual arguments
Traceback: 
1. install.packages("ggplot2", lib.loc = .libPaths()[2], repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
2. getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib, ...)